# The Green Glass Door, Revisited

Tags: language, word-property

I'm sure you've all heard of the famed Gr**ee**n Gla**ss** D**oo**r:

- A bu**tt**erfly can go through the door, but a moth can't.
- A sh**ee**p can go through the door, but a horse can't.

etc.

However, **I have found a door of a different color!**

> - A wasp can go through the door, but a bee can't.
> - An orange can go through the door, but an apple can't.
> - A soldier can go through the door, but a sailor can't.
> - A ninja can go through the door, but a gladiator can't.
> - Silver can go through the door, but gold can't.

**What is the obvious choice for the color of *this* door?** Why?

<sub>Any colors directly mentioned in this puzzle are not eligible to be the color of the door.</sub>

Comment: Whoops, deleted my comment by accident. Haha

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure if this is the answer, but the example words that can go through the door...

> **have no common words that rhyme**: 
>  - *wasp* only rhymes with the rare *knosp*, while *bee* rhymes with *see*, *tee*, *fee*...
>  - *orange* rhymes with "*door hinge*", I guess, but that's two words anyways. *Apple* rhymes with the way more common *grapple* and *chapel*.
>  - *soldier* rhymes with unusual surnames such as *Folger*. *Sailor* and *tailor*, however, are both perfectly normal words.
>  - *ninja* almost rhymes with *ginger*, but not quite. *Gladiator* has countless rhyming words, like *dictator*.
>  - *silver* rhymes with *chilver*, a female lamb, and also a word you won't encounter ever. *Gold* of course rhymes with *old*, or *sold*.

Hence, the door could be...

> **Purple**, or maybe **beige**.

Comment: Very nice!  I'll let this one get a few more views before handing out the green v.

Comment: One of those two colors is a little more well-known for its [tag:word-property]. That's the one I'm looking for.

Comment: The relevant Wikipedia page claims that neither of those is quite an example. And of course "door" no longer works so well. Perhaps you want a rot13(oebamrq byvir sblre) or something of the sort.

Comment: But... Rot13(avawn qbrf eulzr cresrpgyl jvgu tvatre. Naq tynqvngbe qbrfa'g eulzr jvgu qvpgngbe. N erny eulzr erdhverf "-nqvngbe" gb fbhaq vqragvpny. "Fcnqvngbe" (vs vg jrer n jbeq" jbhyq eulzr. Qvpgngbe qbrfa'g (nyfb gur rzcunfvf vf jebat, nf qvpgngbe vf rzcunfvfrq ba gur frpbaq flyynoyr).)

Answer (score 10):

I realize NudgeNudge got the expected answer, but another pattern also exists:

> If A = 1, B = 2, etc, then the first 2 letters of the words that go through the door 
>  have a sum greater than 22, while the words that don't, don't.

**Edit**

A door color which actually fits this pattern is

> Red. The two first letters sum to $23$ and any word with this sum or higher passes through the door.

Comment: This is a nice observation, but it doesn't answer the question: what is the color of the door, then? (honest question here, I mean just because @NudgeNudge got the expected answer doesn't mean that there isn't *another* answer that is consistent with *your* observation).

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier Well, there is a color which actually fits...red. The first two letters have a sum of $23$ and any word with this sum or more, goes through. :-)

Comment: Sure, but it should be in your answer, not in a comment :)